# Understanding voice voil actuator vendor specifications

Tags: control, solenoid, specifications

I'm thinking of potentially using a linear voice coil actuator to move a 90 g mass between 0 mm and 1 mm and back in the horizontal direction with a frequency of 20 Hz. Assuming triangular acceleration, I [calculated the required peak force](https://www.h2wtech.com/page/linear-motion-calculator) to be at least 0.57 N, but assuming sinusoidal acceleration this jumps to 1.4 N, and for 1/3 trapezoidal acceleration this requires 2.6 N.

I've never used a VCA before, and I'm having some trouble translating this specification into the language used by VCA vendors. Specifically, I have three questions:

1. What's the most typical acceleration curve for a VCA? Beyond the obvious force/power requirements, is there an advantage for one vs. another if I just want to get from 0 mm to 1 mm and back at 20 Hz? Otherwise the triangular acceleration is looking mighty attractive.
2. What continuous/peak force specifications should I aim for, given this specification? Most vendors I've found specify the peak force with a 10% duty cycle, but to be honest I'm not really sure what duty cycle I'd need for my desired 20 Hz motion. [I know that](https://www.h2wtech.com/category/voice-coil-actuators#technical1) $$F_\text{average@duty cycle} \approx \frac{F_\text{continuous}}{\sqrt{\text{duty cycle}\%/100}}$$
   but I don't see any specification like a torque-angular velocity product of a normal DC motor so I'm unsure what else the duty cycle affects.
3. Can a traditional stepper motor driver be used to control a VCA? For example, a [DM 556 stepper motor driver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08J3NFF9V) seems to allow for constant voltage, programmable current output. Are these drivers sufficient for open loop control, or is there a disadvantage of using stepper motor drivers for controlling VCAs? [This page](https://www.h2wtech.com/category/voice-coil-actuators#operatingInfo1) also recommends DC linear servo amplifiers, but those are much more expensive from what I've seen.

Any advice on any of these three questions would be much appreciated. If preferred, [this is one example of a VCA I was looking at](https://www.moticont.com/lvcm-016-010-01.htm) which brought up these questions, but I mean to ask these questions more generally as well. I also have the option of including a mechanical advantage into the flexure I'm attaching the VCA and load to for support/linear guidance to convert the VCA's full stroke into my desired 1 mm, if necessary to enable open loop control.

Comment: your 1st link has errors. They show velocity v(t) to appear like the waveshape of acceleration which is wrong. Velocity is the integral of a [g]

Comment: The calculator has errors.  What do you need ? lowest current or cleanest sine position vs time?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Other than the naming ("triangular acceleration" --> "triangular velocity" with two constant acceleration, i.e. constant current, phases), the math itself appears to be correct unless I'm mistaken? I'm not particularly current limited, and I only really care about the end points, i.e. getting between 0 and 1mm in 25 ms and back in another 25 ms (so 20 Hz cyclical motion).
Edit: My current limit is more dependent on Q3 - for example, the DM 556 driver goes up to 5.6A, and the sample VCA I listed has continuous force 1.6 N and force constant 1.1 N/A, so not really limited.

Comment: So, you really don't care how long it dwells at the end points? How accurate does the distance travelled need to be?

Comment: @Mattman944 No, at least not for the purpose of this question. If there's an eddy current/cooling reason to use a trapezoidal vs. triangular curve, though, I'd love to know for future reference. I eventually plan to add a potentiometer/bend sensor for CL feedback, but I'm focused on open loop at the moment, so say +/- 100um or so?

Comment: Vertical or horizontal? or ?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Horizontal and linear. I'm moving a 90g mass, and my VCA is planned to be mounted to a flexure structure for support/linear guidance. I'll update my question to match.

Comment: Does the load ever change? A tiny motor is like a current source and depends on load. A big motor is like a voltage source and not affected by load.. So it matters as well as efficiency and heat radiators, bearing friction, aging, MTBF , duty factor,  there are still a lot of unknowns

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The load is planned to be constant. I'm well aware that I'm leaving out much of the "engineering" side of this question, and I plan to do this analysis before actually buying a part. I'm just trying to understand the terminology used by VCA vendors, since some specs differs from the DC micromotors/servo motors/stepper motors I've used before and I haven't found much online literature on these tradeoffs.

Comment: 90 g mass (as a load) is mentioned - is there a frictional component associated with this mass? If not, you can "tune" this mechanical system to 20 Hz - doing so will relax the current required of the driver, and more closely approach sinusoidal motion. I've done this with loudspeakers by adding mass to the moving cone to shift resonance down in frequency, for example. From the driver's point-of-view, coil impedance increases at resonance, so less current is needed.

Comment: The position profile vs time is important because the control loop may not be trivial. Like Glen said, if your position can be sinusoidal, then you could even add a spring at resonant frequency to help. If position is sinusoidal, then velocity and acceleration are sinusoidal also, the control will be easier.

Comment: Did you consider a standard motor with crankshaft drive or excenter?

Comment: @glen_geek I estimated the frictional force to be about 13 mN based on the surface the mass will be sliding on. Not insignificant, but potentially small enough to use a spring ~(2*pi*20 Hz)^2 * 90g = 1420 N/m. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Mattman944 I see, is there a reason why sinusoidal control will be easier than, say, a triangular velocity control scheme? I imagine any method could be calibrated well enough, but if there's a physical reason (eddy currents, etc.) or maybe just some controls reason I'm unaware of I'd love to hear!

Comment: @Jens Yes, I've also specced out a crankshaft drive and CAM. They have a lot of advantages, but I wanted to provide a comparison spec for a VCA solution in case its contained form factor can win me over. Hence the OP question, since I realized I didn't understand some of the specs VCA vendors give for their VCAs.

Comment: If you go with a VC, you need to decide if you can get away with some type of calibrated open-loop system, or if you need a closed-loop system. Do you have any control loop theory background? If not, this could easily become a much larger task than you realize. You might also look for complete off-the-shelf closed loop solutions, I don't know what might be available out there.

Comment: @Mattman944 Thanks for the warning! I have a bit of control theory background, albeit limited to hobbyist projects mostly. Beyond eddy currents, which I'm not entirely sure how to model, the current input seems pretty close to a proportional gain input term, which you can then control via frequency/Bode techniques I imagine? Like I mentioned in a previous comment, I can also just change the mechanical advantage of the flexure if end-to-end movement is easier than position-calibrated movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all the responses! To answer my own question, here were my conclusions, partially drawn from [this guide](https://www.moticont.com/pdf/linear-dc-motor-force-calculation.pdf) from Moticont.

1. Trapezoidal is one of the more common velocity profiles, since linear velocity slopes = constant acceleration = constant current input, but sinusoidal velocity curves are common as well. A 1/3 trapezoidal velocity profile consumes the least power, a triangular velocity profile has the fastest move time given the same acceleration (obviously), and the sinusoidal curve just seems to be easier to analyze in terms of traditional control theory and in terms of easy of programming if controlling using a traditional audio amp or function generator.
2. According to Moticont, you want $$F_{rms,desired}$$ to be equal or less than the continuous force rating of the motor, and $$P = RI_{rms}^2 = R(F_{rms}/K_f)^2$$ = the coil resistance * (RMS force / force constant)^2 to be equal or less than the max continuous power rating of the motor. The duty cycle affects the trapezoidal and triangular profiles as $$F_{rms,duty} = F_{rms,100\%}/\sqrt{duty\ cycle \ \% / 100}$$ and $$I_{rms,duty} = I_{rms,100\%}\sqrt{duty\ cycle \ \% / 100}$$
3. VCAs are current-controlled devices, so any controller that can operate within the desired voltage range and convert your desired input (say, PWM from an Arduino/Teensy) into variable current in the desired power range should work. From what I've seen online, most stepper motors (although you have to check that the current is programmable), some DC servo drivers/amplifiers, and audio amplifiers should work.

Answer (score 1):

**The correct terminology is Newtons per Amp or N/A and Watts Average Continuous** which is rated at maximum temperature that you may wish to avoid.

From P= V^2/R   V=sqrt(P * R)= 4W * 1.8 ohms = 2.7V rms = 7.6Vpp

With L = 0.2 mH , it reaches 1.8 Ohms @  144 Hz with no load  so neglecting L is OK. With low resistance mass across the L reduces in frequency about 10% so no issue.

The max RMS current is I=sqrt(P/R) = sqrt(4W/1.8) = 1.5 A rms max. or 2.1A pk for a sine and the max peak sine force is 2.1A* 1.1 N/W = 2.31 N

*So if your 1/3 trapezoid force is 2.6 N pk then you need two actuators in parallel and reduce the voltage and temp rise.*

[image]

[image]

.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm having some trouble connecting this back to my original question about converting my specs to the language of a VCA vendor, though. What I'm taking away so far is (a) any waveform works, but triangular waveforms will require less voltage, (b) my force spec is mostly correct, but needs to include the bias spring's deformation force, and (c) a unipolar stepper motor driver will have issues, but a bipolar one should be OK. Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding? Thank you!

Comment: I also realized that my listed DM556 stepper motor controller has a DIR input, so theoretically it should be symmetric about 0 like you mentioned. I also have the option of adjusting my flexure mounting to include a mechanical advantage to transform a VCA's full range to the 1mm desired, if that's a problem. I'll update my question to match.

Comment: Thank you very much for the updated answer! If you don't mind me asking, how does duty cycle play into this force estimate? [Supposedly](https://www.h2wtech.com/category/voice-coil-actuators#technical1) F_avg = F_continuous / sqrt(duty cycle %/100), so the force increases as the duty cycle decreases, but I don't see how this might come out of your analysis.

Comment: corect since the power is exerted in the resistance % d.f = Vavg and I avg, then VI=P is sqrt (d.f.). and that helps reduce power. But you also have active current limit. so you can drive with a square wave and 80% of the slew time is limited by t=0.35/f-3dB = 243 us